# How to stop led torch/flashlight app using Reflection in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7.1.1

I am making an Flashlight app, in which I need to use the camera's LED constantly on pressing ON button and OFF it on pressing the same button. I followed this article [Turning on the LED with the video camera using Reflection](http://www.locked.nl/wp7-flashlight-getting-started). The ON/OFF operation works fine only once. The Code is as:

```
 private VideoCamera _videoCamera;
 private VideoCameraVisualizer _videoCameraVisualizer;
 bool _isFlashOff = true;

 private void FlashButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_isFlashOff)
            {
                _isFlashOff = false;

                // Check to see if the camera is available on the device.
                if (PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.Primary))
                {
                   // Use standard camera on back of device.
                    _videoCamera = new VideoCamera();
                   // Event is fired when the video camera object has been initialized.
                    _videoCamera.Initialized += VideoCamera_Initialized;

                    // Add the photo camera to the video source
                    _videoCameraVisualizer = new VideoCameraVisualizer();
                    _videoCameraVisualizer.SetSource(_videoCamera);
                }
            }
            else
            {                    
                _isFlashOff = true;
                _videoCamera.StopRecording();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void VideoCamera_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _videoCamera.LampEnabled = true;
        _videoCamera.StartRecording();
    }
```

Since there was no implementation of **StopRecording** Method in VideoCamera class as specified in the article: [Turning on the LED with the video camera using Reflection](http://www.locked.nl/wp7-flashlight-getting-started) . I made the function as:

```
 public void StopRecording()
    {
        // Invoke the stop recording method on the video camera object.
         _videoCameraStopRecordingMethod.Invoke(_videoCamera, null);
    }
```

The problem is when I again press ON button "Exception' is thrown as "TargetInvocationException". I am unable to figure out the problem that causes exception. Is StopRecording() function right..??

Comment: How are you instanciating `_videoCameraStopRecordingMethod` ?

Comment: I have declared it as : private MethodInfo _videoCameraStopRecordingMethod and Instantiated as _videoCameraStopRecordingMethod =videoCameraType.GetMethod("StopRecording"); is anything wrong with the public void StopRecording() method...??

Comment: Can anybody help me with this..?? How I need to create StopRecording() method...??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you should initialize the camera only once. Do it during the `OnNavigatedTo` event, then re-use the same instances:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {                    
        // Use standard camera on back of device.
        _videoCamera = new VideoCamera();

        // Event is fired when the video camera object has been initialized.
        _videoCamera.Initialized += VideoCamera_Initialized;


        // Add the photo camera to the video source
        _videoCameraVisualizer = new VideoCameraVisualizer();
        _videoCameraVisualizer.SetSource(_videoCamera);
    }

    private void VideoCamera_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isInitialized = true;
    }

    bool isInitialized;
    bool isFlashEnabled;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isInitialized)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please wait during camera initialization");
            return;
        }

        if (!isFlashEnabled)
        {
            isFlashEnabled = true;

            // Check to see if the camera is available on the device.
            if (PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.Primary))
            {
                _videoCamera.LampEnabled = true;
                _videoCamera.StartRecording();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            isFlashEnabled = false;

            _videoCamera.StopRecording();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Awesum reply.... Thanks a lot..!!!! KooKiz...You saved my day...Realy thanks for the reply... Just a question again how can I can achieve the blink functionality to this flashlight..??

Comment: @Shaan_14 I guess, put a timer and alternatively turn on and off the flashlight when it ticks

Comment: Just a issue with the code when I press Back button to move to MainPage and again navigate to Flashlight Page I get the "TargetInvocationException" exception in line _videoCameraVisualizer.SetSource(_videoCamera); of  OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) method. Whereas If I press Windows Button or search button it starts working..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202949.aspx